# Writing to serial device using Tkinter entry widget in Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to Python, and to the raspberry Pi, which I am using to write this code. I need to send serial commands to a device connected to the raspberry Pi, which will in turn generate frequencies depending on my commands. To connect it to the serial device, I use the code shown below.

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate = 115200, timeout=3.0)
```

If I was to write a direct command to the serial device, it works fine.

```
port.write(b"f1000.0W0.0")
```

The command shown above will allow a signal of 1000MHz to be generated. However, I need to be able to use an entry system that can take whatever number I enter, and not just the ones hardcoded in. For this, I tried using an entry widget.

```
from tkinter import *
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate = 115200, timeout=3.0)


def show_entry_fields():
   print("Frequency in MHz: %s\nPower in dB: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

def close_window(): 
    master.destroy()

def send_to_sig_gen():
    print(b"f.0W0.0")
    port.write(b"f%s.0W0.0" % (e1.get()))

master = Tk()
master.title("FYP1 GUI")
Label(master, text="Frequency (MHz)").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(master, text="Power (dB)").grid(row=1, column=0)

master.minsize(width=250, height=75)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)


Button(master, text='Exit', command=close_window).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Display', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Send', command=send_to_sig_gen).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

***def send_to_sig_gen():*** is supposed to take the "Frequency" value from the entry widget and write a command to the serial device, but instead I get the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/Python_codes/fyp_gui_I.py", line 16, in send_to_sig_gen
      port.write(b"f%s.0W0.0" % (e1.get()))
NameError: name 'port' is not defined
```

I am unsure what I need to do next as the word 'port' is what is used to show the serial destination, shown at the top of the code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I copy and paste your code into a file locally and run it...I don't get that error.  It is able to communicate with a serial device I have locally without a problem (running `python3-3.5.4` under Fedora 25).

Comment: I will check again, perhaps I need to update my python.